# How do IDE's "know" when an object needs to be in a try/catch block?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, intellij-idea, try-catch

Sometimes when I'm coding in Java I will forget to put some code in a try/catch block. Both Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea warn me to put it in a try catch block or make the function throw an exception.

My question is, how do the IDE's recognize when my code needs to be in a try/catch? Also, how does the IDE know what type of exception should be thrown?
For example:

```
// Bad
private static void makeConnection(){
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("someConnection", "someLogin", "somePassword");
}

// Good
private static void makeConnection() throws SQLException{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("someConnection", "someLogin", "somePassword");
}

// Also Good
private static void makeConnection(){
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("someConnection", "someLogin", "somePassword");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think `throws SQLException` in function declaration means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the checked exception in this method definition:

```
private static void makeConnection() throws SQLException
```

If you try to invoke `makeConnection()` without using a `try/catch` or adding a `throws` declaration to the consuming method, you'll get the same warning.

The `DriverManager.getConnection()` method simply has the same `throws` declaration.  The IDE is just responding to that checked exception declaration.